# Custom sort on product related list on opportunity in professional edition

Tags: apex, professional-edition

I have a standard product related list on opportunity which needs to be sorted based on a custom field. Also I need the sort to persist, so that if another quotation is generated from the Oppty, the order in which the products are sorted should carry over to the quote that is generated.
How can this be done in a professional edition where I cannot use apex classes to implement a custom sort?

Answer (score 2):

By default, sorting happens by the SortOrder field. For the standard UI and the standard functionality, we found no way to change it. Even with APEX that field was not writable. The only method I found to change the order programmatically was [Sorting Opportunity Line Items programmatically](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/9291/sorting-opportunity-line-items-programmatically). Even that seems not to work. That's ridiculous.

But you are not alone: https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000Bqu4AAC
This is standing rock solid since 5 years...

With PE also enhanced synchronization (more than what comes out of the box) could give you a very hard time. All the solutions I know need EE or above.

Facing the limitations of the standard handling of products in Opps and Quotes what we did was to replace the entire UI and especially the PDF generator for Quotes. So the built-in SortOrder was no longer in use. But with PE again, this is not possible.

What could theoretically help would be an "Aloah" App from AppExchange, which support the PE. But not sure if there is any. I thought at least Cameleon was supporting PE, but it's actually not: https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N300000016cGxEAI

Answer (score 0):

We have custom Sort Button as part of following Appexchange Product - https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000007r2QFEAY

Please check if this helps. Don't forget to check PDF Generator as well which shows the sorted Line Items in PDF - https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N3000000B4AsxEAF